# How to call callback function within loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get the data from the callback function in forEach loop but it seems to be doesn't work properly as the loop ends before the callback function called. Here is my function:

```
function convertImgToBase64URL(url, callback, outputFormat) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = function () {
        var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS'),
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'), dataURL;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        canvas.width = img.width;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
        callback(dataURL);
        canvas = null;
    };
    img.src = url;
}
```

and the code from where I am calling this function is like that:

```
 angular.forEach(alarms, function (alarm) {
                    convertImgToBase64URL(alarm.photo, function (base64Img) {
                        alarmInfo.push({
                            severity: alarm.payload.severity,
                            from: alarm.name,
                            location: alarm.location,
                            alarmTime: alarm.time,
                            photo: base64Img,
                            contextId: alarm.id
                        });
                        $log.info(base64Img);
                     });
              
            });
```

Is there any way to keep the loop wait until the callback function complete and then continue the loop?

Comment: Look into Promises.

Comment: Why do you want the loop to 'wait'?